# How to set image in a container as a background in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, background-image, assets, cardview

I want to design a custom component card, an image attached in the card, title section will be overleaping on the image section, and description will be added below image section. how to overleap a text on an image in flutter?

```
class CardWithImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title, buttonText;
  final String subTitle;
  final String body;
  final asset;

  CardWithImage({
    this.title,
    this.subTitle,
    this.body,
    this.asset,
    this.buttonText,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: ThemeColors.primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: ThemeColors.grey5,
            blurRadius: 10,
            spreadRadius: 5,
            offset: Offset(3, 3),
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            asset,
            height: 200,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[I want to create a card like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw2HU.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can Achieve your desire card using following code.

```
Container(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
              height: 50,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "Title",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text(
            "Your Big Text ",
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/background.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child:<Widget that needs to be in foreground>
        ......
```